# Using an expression to remove part of a string

Tags: php, regex

This is probably simple however I am not the best with expressions..
I am trying to get the following string from..

```
http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172
```

to this.. using an expression that will remove the ?&SITEID and the dynamic id which will vary

```
http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838
```

Can anyone suggest the best/simplest method to do this?

Comment: Do you mean anything past `?` or just siteid?

Comment: Just want to remove anything past &SITEID - so any other querystring parts remain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this function:

```
$str = 'http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172';

function remove_query_arg($var, $url = NULL){
    if(!$url){
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);

    $query_vars = explode('&', $parsed_url['query']);


    foreach($query_vars as $key => $value){
        $query_vars[$key] = explode('=', $query_vars[$key]);
        $query_variables[$query_vars[$key][0]] = $query_vars[$key][1];
    }

    if(is_array($var)){
        foreach($var as $value){
            unset($query_variables[$value]);
        }
    }
    elseif(is_string($var)){
        unset($query_variables[$var]);
    }

    $query_vars = array();

    foreach($query_variables as $key => $value){
        $query_vars[] = $key.($value !== NULL || !empty($value) ? '='.$value : '');
    }
    $query_str = '';
    $query_str = implode('&',$query_vars);

    return (isset($parsed_url['scheme']) && !empty($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'].'://' : '').$parsed_url['host'].(isset($parsed_url['path']) && !empty($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '').(!empty($query_str) ? '?'.$query_str : '');
}

echo remove_query_arg('SITEID', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a URL, so parse it as one, with **[`parse_url()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)**.

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172";
$parts = parse_url($url);

$url = $parts["scheme"] . "://" . $parts["host"] . $parts["path"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using explode function returns an array

```
$url=http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172
$result=explode('?',$url)
print_r($result);
```

**output**

```
array
{
 [0]=>http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838
 [1]=>?&SITEID=2172
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A valid URL only has one `?` so you can just use `explode` to break it into 2 parts

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172";
list($path, $query) = explode("?", $url, "2");
var_dump($path);
```

Output

```
string 'http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838' (length=34)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838?&SITEID=2172"; 
$str = substr($url, strpos($url, 0, "?&SITEID"));
// $str results in "http://www.yoursite.com/offers/838"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the part before the `?` you can search

```
^(.+?)(\?&SITEID|$)
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

You search non greedily *from the beginning of the line* `^` to the first `?&SITEID` and leave out the rest. If no `?&SITEID` is found you get the entire line by arriving at the end of the string with `$`

`|` is the OR operator that tells the regex "Stop at the first `?&SITEID` or at the end of the string"

**EDIT**:

After the comment where you explain your need to keep the rest of the querystring I suggest you a different approach: find

```
&?SITEID=[^&\s]+
```

being

- `&?` an optional & at the beginning of the string
- `SITEID=` the string you are looking for followed by
- `[^&\s]+` any number of non`&`, nonspace character

and remove it from the string. However, being this the case, I'd go with a non-regex, url-specific approach like suggested in the other answers.